# Spyder can't find installed modules with pip

Tags: python, pip, spyder

I first installed Spyder and then afterwards Python on a server (with Windows Server 2019) all on the directory "C:\Users\wi932\ .spyder-py3" and the Python folder "C:\Users\wi932\Python\Python38". Then I installed many packages (like tensorflow, matplotlib, scikitlearn) by using the command prompt of windows and pip from the directory "C:\Users\wi932\Python\Python38\Scripts" and it was okay.

However, when running Spyder I can't use the packages that I installed using pip. Whenever I run a Python programm with those modules I get an error message "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'". So the question is how can I build a "connection" between the pip and Spyder?

Does anyone have an idea? I'll appreciate every comment.

Comment: Maybe you are missing changing the interpreter configuration inside Spyder to point to your Python installation? The preference is at `Preferences > Python interpreter > Python interpreter `. Also, to be able to use the custom interpreter you will need to install in your Python installation the correct `spyder-kernels` version. For more info checking the Spyder docs page could be worthy: https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/faq.html and https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/troubleshooting/first-steps.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered installing anaconda?

Spyder comes as a part of this and is easy to install from the anaconda client. You can also create your base environment in the anaconda client and then switch to pip to install packages from there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Rasmus. I have made quite bad experience with Anaconda (many errors). This is why I decided not to use Anaconda anymore.

Comment: Have you tried using Pycharm then? It's what I am using and so far it has been very easy to setup environments and attach them.

In fact it's how I am running things on our windows VM.